# Conflict between 'ShowText' and 'LineStyle' in the contourf function in MATLAB R2019a?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contourf, linestyle, showtext

I'm using the code as follows. But the figures are different when I run my code in MATLAB R2014a and R2019a (in the same computer, Win7 64bit). It seems there is a conflict between `'ShowText'` and `'LineStyle'` in function `contourf` in MATLAB R2019a ? What I want is the figure with text and no line (like the figure by R2014a). How can I get that in R2019a?

```
for i = 1 : 10
    for j = 1 : 10
        res(i, j) = i * j;
    end
end
contourf(res, 'ShowText', 'on', 'LineStyle', 'none');
```

**Figure using R2014a**

[image: figure by R2014a]

**Figure using R2019a**

[image: figure by R2019a]

**Figure using R2019a using `contourf(res, 'ShowText', 'on')` only**

[image: figure by R2019a using "contourf(res, 'ShowText', 'on') only]

Comment: You can use `contourf(res, 'ShowText', 'on','LineColor', 'flat');` so the LineColor will be the same as the contour color and look "transparent". But your code should also work, this is probably a bug that need to be reported to MathWork.

Comment: @obchardon I think that's a good solution

Comment: @obchardon That's perfect! I've ever tried contourf(res, 'ShowText', 'on','LineWidth', 0); but it's not allowed by MATLAB. I haven't thought of using LineColor. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of research I found this solution with the help of [undocumented MATLAB](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-contour-plots):

```matlab
for i = 1 : 10
for j = 1 : 10
res(i, j) = i * j;
end
end
[c,hC] = contourf(res);
clabel(c,hC)
drawnow; % Important !
set(hC.EdgePrims(:),'Visible','off');
```

Which gives this result in `R2017b` :
[image]

**Disclaimer:**
This solution relies on an undocumented feature of MATLAB, the results may vary depending on your version.

**R2018a**

[Sardar Usama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698672/sardar-usama) came up with an alternative solution for `R2018a`in the comments :

```
%drawnow; % Important !
%set(hC.EdgePrims(:),'Visible','off');
delete(hc.EdgePrims);
```

Comment: or you can just `delete(hC.EdgePrims)` instead of drawnow and setting visibilty off

Comment: @SardarUsama I did not managed to make it work, do not hesitate to improve my answer !

Comment: To rephrase: instead of the last two lines, you can use `delete(hC.EdgePrims);`

Comment: @SardarUsama Unfortunately this does not work when I try it.. (in `R2017b`)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "does not work" but I have verified it in R2018a. if you delete the EdgePrims, there will be no EdgePrims. But undocumented features can't be expected to behave as the documented ones. So...

Comment: @SardarUsama I meant removing the 2 last lines and replacing them by `delete(hC.EdgePrims);` does not provide the expected result. The EdgePrims are not effectively deleted when I test your solution in R2017b, so yes it seems to be a version issue.

Comment: @Arthur when I run this on R2019a, the lines are still shown in the figure. So maybe this issue appears after R2018a ?

Comment: @JQY It looks like some things have changed.. Did the workaround in `R2018a` worked ?